# Can I instruct the browser not to look for a favicon?

Tags: html, favicon

I have a website that doesn't have/need a favicon.

Is there a way to instruct the browser not to waste a request looking for /favicon.ico ?

I don't mean filtering logs, but something client-side, like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="about:blank" />
```

That appears to work, but I'm not in a position to do comprehensive tests, (and search engines are being unhelpful).

Can anyone confirm if this is a valid method, or provide a suitable alternative?

**Update:** On further investigation, that *doesn't* work (at least not with Chromium 18 on a non-local domain). A partial solution is using a `data:` URL to serve a base64 blank image, ([example from here](http://davidwalsh.name/blank-favicon)):

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQEAYAAABPYyMiAAAABmJLR0T///////8JWPfcAAAACXBIWXMAAABIAAAASABGyWs+AAAAF0lEQVRIx2NgGAWjYBSMglEwCkbBSAcACBAAAeaR9cIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This is working, but has two down-sides:

- It will presumably fail in browsers that don't support data URLs.
- It results in no favicon at all - i.e. it hides the browser default icon.

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests) on SO ?

Comment: Nope, thanks for the link. Going on from Max's "use a blank file" comment, I'm wondering if `<link href="data:image/x-icon;" rel="shortcut icon" />` is a valid solution - seems like it might be working (shows browser default), but need to test how IE7/others respond to it.

Comment: Just tried on IE8 and it displays the default favicon

Comment: Hmm, hidden in a non-obvious link in an answer to that question is a related question on SO with lots of answers/comments - doesn't appear to be anything new/useful, but in case I've missed stuff [here's the link anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199902/isnt-it-silly-that-a-tiny-favicon-requires-yet-another-http-request-how-to-mak).

Comment: Thanks. Uses default in IE9 too. Is a shame there isn't an easy way to test how it responds in IE7, since I think that's the one with data URL problems?

Comment: [It might be worth noting here that sites which are generally *extremely* concerned about performance, page size, requests, etc., and with likely better reason, eg. Google, Yahoo, for the most part just go ahead and create an icon and move on to more important problems.]

Comment: Have you tried to remove the favicon from your site?.

Comment: Just a question; is your site an internal network one, or one with a small number of users?  What if one of your users like Favicons due to them having 42 tabs open, or liek seeing an icon in their Bookmarks list?  Just asking from a [ux.se] perspective.

Comment: @PeterBoughton an additional downside is if you're serving non-HTML content. If the content type is, say "application/json" the browser is still making a request for a favicon. I can block or serve the request with controls on the server, but it's still making the request. I'd rather have the browser just never make the request via header or something practical for other content where a favicon isn't always relevant.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I just went and did some testing with a bunch of random browsers I happened to have installed, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and [a simple web page](http://favicontest.vyznev.net/blank.html) containing the tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="about:blank">
```

Here are the results so far:

- **Chromium 18.0** on Ubuntu Linux: **Works.**  No requests for `/favicon.ico`, no favicon shown.
- **Google Chrome 21.0** on Windows XP: **Works.**
- **Firefox 15.0.1** on Ubuntu Linux: **Inconsistent behavior.**  Apparently, Firefox shows no favicon and makes no HTTP request for `/favicon.ico` on the *first* page load.  However, when the page is visited the *second* time, `/favicon.ico` is loaded and displayed.
- **Firefox 15.0** on Windows XP: **Inconsistent behavior,** same as above.
- **Opera 10.10** on Ubuntu Linux: **Doesn't work.**  Requests `/favicon.ico` but does not show it.
- **Konqueror 4.8.4** on Ubuntu Linux: **Works.**
- **rekonq 0.9.1** on Ubuntu Linux: **Broken.**  Tries to request `/about:blank` from the server.
- **Internet Explorer 8.0** on Windows XP: **Inconsistent(?).**  Seemed to be working at first, but `/favicon.ico` was requested at some point, most likely after I visited another page and used the back button.  Testing was somewhat complicated by the fact that, for some reason, IE is refusing to actually render my test favicons.  Needs more testing.

#### Other notes:

Browsers tend to cache favicons pretty damn aggressively.  Normal methods for clearing the browser cache don't always seem to work; I had to run the browsers with brand new sandboxed profiles to get consistently repeatable results.  Notably, reconq at least will fall back to showing the (non-default) favicon from *another page on the same site* if it has one cached.

Answer (score 2):

Added the code 
still got error on "about:blank"
Then changed to code below:
No more error message from Chrome Developer Tool.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
```